# Python creating wordcloud no output

Tags: python, matplotlib, word-cloud

I am creating a wordcloud from a dictionary, for the wordcloud I use the library wordcloud created by the github user amueller.

This is my code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    MyData= {u'arbeid': 0.0006715695865686539,
      u'banen': 0.00066821988636323406,
      u'begrotingsherstel': 0.00071106447864468028,
      u'belastingplan': 0.00064287666559415511,
      u'bestuursakkoord': 0.00085938678272561703,
      u'duurzame': 0.00086622249359887991,
      u'energie': 0.00071735256545447078,
      u'energievoorziening': 0.00091959448177479836,
      u'europa': 0.00077342364155819174,
      u'inkomens': 0.00086651160197001511,
      u'kabinet': 0.0012281373248267241,
      u'pakket': 0.00078934462283374919,
      u'premier': 0.00098440752486735842,
      u'slob': 0.0010329596055417033,
      u'verdaas': 0.00072183114176594104}

    type(test)

    WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(MyData)
    plt.show()
```

The problem that I have is that if i do not use `plt.show()` than I only get the following as output:

```
<wordcloud.wordcloud.WordCloud at 0x350700f0>
```

If I recall correctly `plt.show()` should draw the object but it is not!

Answer (score 5):

You have to save result of `WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(MyData)` to variable and then use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` to plot it.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# test data
MyData= {u'arbeid': 0.0006715695865686539,
      u'banen': 0.00066821988636323406,
      u'begrotingsherstel': 0.00071106447864468028,
      u'belastingplan': 0.00064287666559415511,
      u'bestuursakkoord': 0.00085938678272561703,
      u'duurzame': 0.00086622249359887991,
      u'energie': 0.00071735256545447078,
      u'energievoorziening': 0.00091959448177479836,
      u'europa': 0.00077342364155819174,
      u'inkomens': 0.00086651160197001511,
      u'kabinet': 0.0012281373248267241,
      u'pakket': 0.00078934462283374919,
      u'premier': 0.00098440752486735842,
      u'slob': 0.0010329596055417033,
      u'verdaas': 0.00072183114176594104}
# generate wordcloud
wcloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(MyData)

# make figure to plot
plt.figure()
# plot words
plt.imshow(wcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
# remove axes
plt.axis("off")
# show the result
plt.show()
```

[image]